# Error when Using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video file from a series of JPGs using the following command:-

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img*.jpg -s 640x480 movie.mpg
```

but it fails after generating a lot of output with the following:-

```
<lots of output, removed>
Stream #0.0 -> #89.0
Stream #0.0 -> #90.0
Stream #0.0 -> #91.0
Stream #0.0 -> #92.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mjpeg @ 0x95dfac0]get_buffer() failed (-1 0 0 (nil))
Video encoding failed
```

What's causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you try ffmpeg -f image2 -i img*.jpg -r 1 -vcodec mjpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -s 640x480 movie.mpg

Answer (score 2):

Glob syntax (`*`) won't work for image sequences. You must use `%d` for indicating where to look for the number (assuming that your image sequence is numbered, otherwise it will not work).
Also you might specify an output framerate with `-r`

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg -r 25 -s 640x480 movie.mpg
```

This takes the images `img0.jpg`, `img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`... and creates a video with 25 frames per second.

Comment: The `%d` instead of `*` was the missing element!